# Misconfigurations of DNS over TCP

Tags: database, parsing, tcp, dns, automation

I am new to python programming and for my project I need to automate some of the misconfiguration cases(by looking into the flow of tcp packets and tcp flags) of DNS over TCP to write into a database. For that I am trying to parse the captured tcp dumps. Can you help of how can I proceed

Answer (score 0):

dig +tcp will tell dig to use TCP:

```
 +[no]tcp
           Use [do not use] TCP when querying name servers. The default
           behavior is to use UDP unless an AXFR or IXFR query is requested,
           in which case a TCP connection is used.
```

that should make grabbing the pcap much simpler